# shortening code for a big amount of textboxes

Tags: vb.net

I have a big number of textboxes in my application contained in a panel. The textboxes are grouped by 4. Example: l1,w1,q1,p1,l2,w2,q2,p2,.... The code inside is working perfectly but taking so much time while compiling.

```
If l24.Text <> "" And w24.Text <> "" And q24.Text <> "" And p24.Text <> "" Then
        counter += 1
        Dim a, b, c, d As Integer
        a = Convert.ToInt16(p24.Text.Substring(0, 1))
        b = Convert.ToInt16(p24.Text.Substring(1, 1))
        c = Convert.ToInt16(p24.Text.Substring(2, 1))
        d = Convert.ToInt16(p24.Text.Substring(3, 1))

        If a = 4 Or a = 5 Or b = 4 Or b = 5 Or c = 4 Or c = 5 Or d = 4 Or d = 5 Then
            forpress += (Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) + pressing) * (Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) + pressing) * (Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text))
        End If
        Select Case a
            Case 1
                half += (Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                ehalf += Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 2
                two += (Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                etwo += Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 3
                three += (Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                ethree += Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 4
                four += (Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                efour += Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 5
                five += (Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                efive += Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
        End Select

        Select Case b
            Case 1
                half += (Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                ehalf += Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 2
                two += (Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                etwo += Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 3
                three += (Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                ethree += Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 4
                four += (Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                efour += Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 5
                five += (Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                efive += Convert.ToInt16(l24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
        End Select

        Select Case c
            Case 1
                half += (Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                ehalf += Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 2
                two += (Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                etwo += Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 3
                three += (Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                ethree += Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 4
                four += (Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                efour += Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 5
                five += (Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                efive += Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
        End Select

        Select Case d
            Case 1
                half += (Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                ehalf += Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 2
                two += (Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                etwo += Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 3
                three += (Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                ethree += Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 4
                four += (Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                efour += Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
            Case 5
                five += (Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) + add) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
                efive += Convert.ToInt16(w24.Text) * Convert.ToInt16(q24.Text)
        End Select

    End If
```

This is an example for one set of textboxes (l24,w24,q24,p24). How can i join all the sets of textboxes to minimize my code lines and compiling time ?
Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Where are the `Case`s for? And why do you have this huge amount of variables? Did you hear about `List(Of T)`s?

Comment: No, not yet. But thx anyway. i will look it up

Comment: Is it possible for you to try using multidimensional arrays? They work well for situations like yours. (Specifically, for you, it is 2D arrays). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2de1t93(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two-dimensional arrays. For example, you have 10 groups of 4 `TextBox` each.

You would use:

```
Dim Values(9, 3) As String
```

because you have 10 groups (0 ~ 9) of 4 elements (0 ~ 3) each.

For example, if you want to read the value from the first `TextBox` in the sixth group:

You would use:

```
Values(5, 0) = l6.Text
```

So the first value in this case refers to the group number and the second refers to the number in that group. It also works the other way around if you prefer. This certainly will reduce the size of your code.

Hope this helped.

Comment: That was just perfect !